# InitializeComponent "doesn't exist" and "no definition" for XAML map controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am working on a simple map app that will zoom into and follow my location using `GeoCoordinateWatcher`. The problem is, whenever I finish putting everything into place, `InitializeComponents()` always throws an exception and my **C#** code won`t recognize my *XAML* map controls. Is this some kind of bug or am I just a total fool?

CODE SAMPLE:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent(); // This whole line is underlined red

    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}


public void CenterUserLocation()
{
    // Center MyMap on user location
    this.MyMap.Center = myPoint; //MyMap is underlined red
    this.MyMap.ZoomLevel = 10;  //MyMap is underlined red
}
```

UPDATE: (Class Definitions C#)

```
namespace MapApp{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
    private Geopoint myPoint;
```

UPDATE: (XAML)

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MapApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
    x:Class="MapApp.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>

            <!-- LOCATION BUTTON -->
            <AppBarButton x:Uid="LocateAppBarButton"
                          x:Name="LocateAppBarButton"
                          Label="location"
                          Icon="Map"
                          Click="LocateAppBarButton_Click" />


        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid>
        <Maps:MapControl x:Name="MyMap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="580" Width="400"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Have you changed your class definition? What is your class inheriting from?

Comment: The class is MainPage : Page (declared in the corresponding xaml file as x:class MapApp.MainPage) I saw some people with changed namespaces having similar problems to me, but my namespaces seem to be fine... I`ve been stumped for quite a while :(

Comment: Well, the odds that it actually throws an exception should be about zero, that can't happen until you can actually compile the code.  There's something wrong with your XAML, we can't see it.  Do use Build + Rebuild first before you do anything drastic.

Comment: Oh, I just answered that about the namespaces :/ I guess that's not your problem...

Can we see your XAML root node and the code-behind class definition, anyway?

Comment: I can only get an "object reference not set to instance of object" error, along with "MapApp.MainPage does not contain reference to InitializeComponent();". My XAML file is just a visual  studio 2013 autogenerated blank phone app template with a drag and drop map control... Nothing too complicated, shall I post it? :)

Comment: None of these solutions work for you? http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/silverlight-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context/ ... Maybe the Build Action thing? Is it set to Page in your case?

Comment: My namespace/classes are identical and MainPage.xaml build action is set to page (It is the same for all projects I have had this problem with, this error is becoming a rather annoying common occurrence...) I just don`t get it! Short of reinstalling everything (Some random guy said this would work), I don`t know what to do! :S

Comment: I just retyped the entire cs file all over again (in a new blank windows phone project) and it still displays this error as soon as I try to edit the xaml  file (I didn`t touch class definitions at all!) I guess there is something wrong with my installation...

Comment: That's a bummer :/ Try reinstalling and see if that works... Let us know!

Comment: After much screwing around, I ended up using VS2012 express for windows phone and the error didn`t occur at all. I have no idea what causes this but it is a total pain in the gonads. Thank you for you help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML and code-behind should be something like this:

XAML:

```
    <Page x:Class="MyNamespace.MyCanvasCodeInline">
    ...
```

Code-behind:

```
    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        public partial class MyCanvasCodeInLine // : Page - not needed but implied
        ...
```

Things you should check:

1. The code-behind class is defined as `partial`
2. The code-behind class qualified name (namespace + class name) is the same as the `x:Class` property of the XAML root node
3. The XAML root node is some class that implements IComponentConnector (Page, Window, UserControl, etc.)

Another way to do this is checking the `xaml.cs` file that gets generated "under" the XAML file, and compare its `partial class` definition with your code-behind class. They should match types, name and namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your XAML file has the correct Build Action (should be Page).  I've seen Visual Studio change this when copy/pasting XAML files between projects.

If this isn't correct, you will get this error even though your class names and namespaces match between your XAML and code-behind.